# Is there is any way to save images url using dynamic anchor tag?

Tags: javascript, image, blob, anchor

I have a service which takes a screenshot and return a promise which is parse using .toDataURL then that URL is split into proper url. 
Now I want to dynamically download the image using the anchor tag

i tried  URL.createObjectURL(imageAsBase64String) but it is giving an error

```
var snapotPromise = SomeApiService.TotakeScreenshot(param); // it return promise 
snapotPromise.then(function onSuccess(iResult) {
    var imageAsBase64String = iResult.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);
    var splittedImage = imageAsBase64String.substr(imageAsBase64String.indexOf(',') + 1)
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = URL.createObjectURL(imageAsBase64String);
    a.download = "saveScreenShot.png";
    a.click();
});
```

Download image with name saveScreenShot.png

Comment: could `a.href = iResult.toDataURL("image/png", 1.0);` work?

Comment: @RolandStarke thank you it worked but is their any other better way like blob ..